# Загрузка новых элементов в ListView, Android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragment, activity

Как реализовать пополнение уже созданного ListView?
Объясню ситуацию, есть список ListView, в него записываются элементы из БД.

Но пользователь может добавить данные в БД но в ListView этого элемента не будет, и для этого я каждый раз при вызове onResume() заново подгружал данные и устанавливал новый адаптер (знаю говнокод еще тот).

И вот эта подгрузка каждый раз затормаживают загрузку самого Activity что очень заметно.

Вопрос собственно заключается вот в чем: как сделать динамическую подгрузку новых данных если они появились, и как сразу их отобразить?

Comment: Не знаю как это для SQLite делается (но как-то, вроде, через курсоры можно), но вот если NOSQL решение Realm использовать, то там из коробки события об изменениях выборки из БД есть. И они в другом потоке легко работают также из коробки. Короче попробуйте Realm+JavaRx

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется вам нужно вызывать метод адаптера `notifyDataSetChanged()` при добавлении новой записи.
Типа этого:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```